# MonthCalendar C# winforms highlight dates color

Tags: c#, date, colors, calendar

I need to hightlight  the date in the monthCalendar control with colors or the background of the day but i only get that date bolded in Winforms

```
 DateTime dt = new DateTime(22, 12, 2014);
            monthCalendar1.AddBoldedDate(dt)
```

thanks.

Comment: You will need to provide more information that gives us some idea of how the styling in your app works. the code you provided is not useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot highlight dates by using the default properties of month calendar.You could go for own [`custom contro`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10840/Another-Month-Calendar)l as mentioned here

Answer (score 0):

Use ajaxcontroltoolkit calendarextender . It is more easy to use.